# Relative import in Django

Tags: python, django, python-import, relative-path

I am currently developing a client/server application. Client and server are both Django projects.

I would like to import client models in the server application. Here is the arborescence of my files :

```
client/
    fileapp/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        ...
    client/
        __init__.py
        ...
    manage.py

server/
    fileapp/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        ...
    server/
        __init__.py
        ...
    manage.py
```

I would like in my server project, import client/fileapp/models. I try to do this with Django shell and make relative import with that instruction :

```
>>> from ..client.fileapp.models import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named client.fileapp.models
```

I also try to append the client path to sys.path but it doesn't work either. If you know how to do kind of that mechanism, please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: is there a `__init__.py` file in the directory containing `client` and `server`?

Comment: I added one in each directory but it does not work

Comment: each directory, *including* `client`'s and `server`'s parent? or only under `client` and `server`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
client/
    fileapp/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        ...
    client/
        __init__.py
        ...
    __init__.py
    manage.py

server/
    fileapp/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        ...
    server/
        __init__.py
        ...
    __init__.py
    manage.py
__init__.py
...
```